# Open a file based on dropdown menu selections

Tags: javascript, html, function, drop-down-menu

web development newbie. I have a page with a radio button and two dropdown menus. The selections for each of these matters, and will determine which file will open up. When each selection is made and the user hits "Submit," I want the page to open up the corresponding Excel file.

I have the radio button and dropdowns built, but when I press submit, nothing happens. I tried doing this in PHP to make it more dynamic and to avoid having so many if/else statements, but PHP does not run properly on my server so I've opted to use JavaScript which will lead to more if statements but will at least be functional.

This is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var excelObject;
    excelObject = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    excelObject.Visible = true;
    excelObject.Workbooks.Open(strLocation, false, boolReadOnly);


    //x, y, and z are the variables for the dropdowns/radio button
    var x = document.getElementByID("x");
    var y = document.getElementByID("y");
    var z = document.getElementByID("z");

    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementByID("x").innerHTML=x;
        document.getElementByID("y").innerHTML=y;
        document.getElementByID("z").innerHTML=z;

    function docOpen(){

        if (x == "test" && y ="cat" && z == "claws"){
            readFile('file:\\folder\folder\test_cat_claws.xls');
```

This is where I add the form:

```
<form name ='myform' method="post" onSubmit="Javascript:docOpen()" >
```

And this is where I press submit:

```
<input type= "submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="Javascript:docOpen(); return false;"/>
```

**EDIT:**
Entire code - edited to be more generic:

```
    <html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <script type="text/javascript">

        var x = document.getElementByID("x");
            var y = document.getElementByID("y");
            var z = document.getElementByID("z");


        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementByID("x").innerHTML=x;
            document.getElementByID("y").innerHTML=y;
            document.getElementByID("z").innerHTML=z;

        function docOpen(){

            if (x == "test" && y =="cat" && z == "claws"){
                          var excelObject;
                          excelObject = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                          excelObject.Visible = true;
                          excelObject.Workbooks.Open('file:\your_excel_file_location_here.xlsx', false, boolReadOnly);    
            }
   </script>

   <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
    <table border="0px"><tr><td>
    <td id="pagetitle"><h1>Page Title</h1></td>

    <td><iframe src="" height="60" width="280" style="border:none" scrolling="no";> </iframe></td></tr></table>
    </div>

    <div id="includedContent"></div>

<div class="main" id="MainContent">


<div class="form_table">

<!--<div class="clear"></div>-->

<form name ='myform'>

<div id="q0" class="q required">
<a class="item" name="radiobutton0"></a>
<table class="inline_grid">
<tr>
<td> <input type="radio" name="x" id="x" value="test" />Test</label></td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="x" id="x" value="test2" />Test2</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="q1" class="q required">
<a class="item" name="dropdown1"></a>
<label>&nbsp;<b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></label>
<select id="y" name="y" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="cat">Cat</option>
<option value="dog">Dog</option>
<option value="bird">Bird </option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q2" class="q required">
<a class="item" name="dropdown2"></a>
<label>&nbsp;<b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></label>
<select id="z" name="z" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="claws">Claws</option>
<option value="paws">Paws</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div><br/>




<input type="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="docOpen();"/>

</form>


    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, since you're utilizing ActiveX objects this code is only going to work in IE

Comment: This code will only execute in IE - makes it a bit harder. @AlexanderEdwards

Comment: Got it working, check my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated. Will make edits to my code and see if it will run. @AlexanderEdwards

Comment: Thanks!  And if it works, please shoot me an upvote/mark me as the answer :)

Comment: See my edits, you may have some difficulties with the additional arguments you have passed to the open() method

Comment: Upon form submission, it still doesn't open the file... Just refreshes the page. Do I have to fix anything in the form or input sections? @AlexanderEdwards

Comment: Yes, sounds like your form submission is refreshing the page, which is the default behavior.  I'll add to my answer.

Comment: See my edits, should do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately it still refreshes the page but I notice that when I hit submit, it shows the variable assignments in the url bar... i.e. file://folder/folder/folder/enterfilename.html?x=test&y=cat&z=claws&Submit=Submit+Query @AlexanderEdwards

Comment: Can you copy all of the code into your answer?

Comment: My mistake actually, looks like I needed to remove the value and name attributes of submit from the <button> to do the trick.  That should do it for sure.. See my edit once again

Comment: button needs to look like this <button  onclick="docOpen(); return;"/>

Comment: When I take out <input type ... etc, it gets rid of the submit button. Should I make the <button> part a separate piece?

Comment: The button part is going to become your new submit 'button'.  So like this: <button onclick="docOpen(); return;">Submit</button>

Comment: Yes, completely remove the input that had the type and value of submit

Comment: Hm, it still refreshes the page... is the onclick calling the function correctly? I've never done javascript within html

Comment: Ok, added my edits with the complete version of the code at the very bottom.  Should certainly work, you'll just need to change the excel path to one of your own.

Comment: It works! Much appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a few things to note:

It appears as though in your logic you were using your comparison operator incorrectly, and using a single `=` instead of two `==` to compare.  Change that to look like this.

```
if (x == "test" && y =="cat" && z == "claws")
```

Additionally, You might be initializing your ActiveXObject too early(?).  Why not create the excel sheet after the condition is met, like so:

```
if (x == "test" && y =="cat" && z == "claws"){
 var excelObject;
    excelObject = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    excelObject.Visible = true;
    excelObject.Workbooks.Open(strLocation, false, boolReadOnly);
```

This way your code won't even bother opening the spreadsheet unless they do meet the specific criteria.

Also, from what I can tell, `readFile()` isn't a valid js function.  You will need to pass your file location into the first argument of the `excelObject.Workbooks.Open` function.  So, all said, your code will look something like this:

```
   //x, y, and z are the variables for the dropdowns/radio button
    var x = document.getElementByID("x");
    var y = document.getElementByID("y");
    var z = document.getElementByID("z");

    window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementByID("x").innerHTML=x;
            document.getElementByID("y").innerHTML=y;
            document.getElementByID("z").innerHTML=z;
            }

    function docOpen(){

        if (x == "test" && y =="cat" && z == "claws"){
            var excelObject;
            excelObject = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            excelObject.Visible = true;
            excelObject.Workbooks.Open('file:\your_excel_file_location_here.xlsx', false, boolReadOnly);    
                }
}
```

And again, do be aware that this will only work in IE given your use of ActiveXObjects.  Maybe that's sufficient for your needs.

**EDIT WITH COMPLETE CODE:**

```
   <html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



   <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
    <table border="0px"><tr><td>
    <td id="pagetitle"><h1>Page Title</h1></td>

    <td><iframe src="" height="60" width="280" style="border:none" scrolling="no";> </iframe></td></tr></table>
    </div>

    <div id="includedContent"></div>

<div class="main" id="MainContent">


<div class="form_table">

<!--<div class="clear"></div>-->

<form name ='myform'>

<div id="q0" class="q required">
<a class="item" name="radiobutton0"></a>
<table class="inline_grid">
<tr>
<td> <input type="radio" name="x" id="x1" value="test" />Test</label></td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="x" id="x" value="test2" />Test2</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="q1" class="q required">
<a class="item" name="dropdown1"></a>
<label>&nbsp;<b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></label>
<select id="y" name="y" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="cat">Cat</option>
<option value="dog">Dog</option>
<option value="bird">Bird </option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q2" class="q required">
<a class="item" name="dropdown2"></a>
<label>&nbsp;<b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></label>
<select id="z" name="z" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="claws">Claws</option>
<option value="paws">Paws</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div><br/>


</form>

<button  onclick="docOpen(); return;">button</button>


    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>

</div>


   <script type="text/javascript">

        function docOpen(){

            var x = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked')[0].value;
            var ySelect = document.getElementById('y');
            var y = ySelect.options[ySelect.selectedIndex].value;
            var zSelect = document.getElementById('z');
            var z = zSelect.options[zSelect.selectedIndex].value;



            if (x == "test" && y =="cat" && z == "claws"){
                          var excelObject;
                          excelObject = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                          excelObject.Visible = true;
                          excelObject.Workbooks.Open('file:\excel.xlsx');    
            }
        }
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```